# What will appear in my global inbox?

Tags: support, global-inbox

What I want to know are the rules that control what appears in my inbox. Is it just answers to my questions and comments with my @name in? To put it another way, do I ever need to pro-actively go and look at questions I've had some input on or will I always be notified about new activity?

Comment: This should help you a bit: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) So basically: Questions you've asked that receive answers/comments, answers you've posted that receive comments, and comment replies to you will all show in your inbox. If you want to keep up to date with the comments and clarifications on a question that you have not asked, you'll want to pro-actively watch said question, in case comments aren't directed at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the things that will cause an inbox notification for you:

- Someone answers your question.
- Someone edits or suggests an edit on your post.
- Someone comments on your post.
- Someone [explicitly @mentions you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) in a post you commented on in the past.
- You receive a private moderator message.
- You have a chat ping that has been sitting around for a while (not dismissed).
- A new phase of an election begins and you are eligible to participate in that phase.
- Your bounty on a question expired or is about to expire.

Comment: For the record, it seems that "a chat ping that has been sitting around for a while" is 15 minutes.